# Django Admin. Do not show any entries until fill something in search_fields

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class PropertyAdmin(ModerationAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', 'value', 'job__job_name', 'description')
    list_display = ('job', 'app', 'name', 'value', 'description', 'pub_date')
    readonly_fields = ('pub_date',)
    list_filter = ('app',)
```

I have more than 5000 objects in a model. I do not want to use pagination, also I do not want to see all 5000 objects on one page while "search_fields" or "list_filter" are empty. 
Is there a way to see **only** search/filter fields and after that to choose necessary objects by filling this fields?

Comment: the default list_per_page is 100, maybe you can reset the number inside  filter/search.

Comment: The thing is I do not want to see neither 5000 nor 100 objects. So list_per_page does not fit.